# Dynamically load all python file in a folder then call the same function in each file and pass in some dataframes?

Tags: python

I have a folder of python scripts, I want to call each of them and pass in a DB object, this is easily doable, but I would like to do it dynamically, that is if I don't know the name of the script beforehand, is this possible?

Let's say all scripts are in the "scripts" subfolder.

My caller file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import scripts.Script1 as MyScript1
import scripts.Script2 as MyScript2
import pandas as pd

_scripts = {
    'MyScript1': MyScript1,
    'MyScript2': MyScript2,
}

def Invoke(DB, script, parameters):
    if script in _scripts:
        curScript = _scripts[script]
        tables = GetTable(DB, curScript)
        result = curScript.Invoke(tables)
        return result

def GetTable(DB, script):
    tables = script.TableToLoad()
    dataframes = {}
    if not isinstance(tables, list):
        tables = [tables]
    for table in tables:
        dataframes[table] = DB.LoadDataframe(table)
    return dataframes
```

The script file:

```
def TableToLoad():
    return ['MyDBTable1']

def Invoke(tables):
    df = tables['MyDBTable1']
    # do useful work here
```

Is something like this dynamically loadable?  Like dynamically load the _scripts variable

Comment: Can't you do this with `glob` and `importlib.import_module`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright figure it out after looking at a few different answers:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import importlib.util 
_scripts = { }

def Init():
    global _scripts
    modules = glob.glob('scripts/*.py')
    for path in modules:
        file_name = os.path.basename(path)
        file_name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(file_name, path)
        module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(module)
        _scripts[file_name] = module
```

The rest is the same

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the files using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) with a pattern like `**/*.py`, which would select all py files inside the directory.

```py
from pathlib import Path

for file in Path('scripts').glob('**/*.py'):
    ...
```

Then you can use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to import all objects from the file.

```py
module = importlib.import_module('.scripts.<filename>')
```

Then you can iterate over all the members using [`inspect.getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers).

```py
for name, member in inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.ismethod):
    if name == 'Invoke':
        member(tables)
```

Depending on the use case it might be better to call the files after all the files are found.